# XML-Schema - No declaration found for element 'impresoras'

Tags: xml, xml-schema

Estoy con el tema de XML-Schema para validar documentos XML, y no consigo localizar el error del archivo. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme...
Tengo creado el archivo XSD y referenciado al archivo XML, pero cuando lo voy a validar me salta el error:

"Error at line 3, column 67: no declaration found for element 'impresoras'"

Ese elemento es el elemento raíz del documento XML.

También me pasa, que cuando valido el archivo XSD, me pone este error:
"Error at line 2, column 87: no declaration found for element 'xs:schema'"

Estoy haciéndolo todo con el programa XML Copy Editor, aunque no me gusta mucho, porque da muchos problemas.

Os dejo aquí los dos documentos, por si alguien pudiera echarme una mano.

DOCUMENTO XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <impresoras xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="yara_doamo_camila_impresoras.xsd">
  <impresora numSerie="i245" tipo="láser" compra="2010">
    <marca>Epson</marca>
    <modelo>EPL300</modelo>
    <peso>4.52</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <tamaño>A5</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-123BV</cartucho>
    <enred/>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i246" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2410</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i247" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2420</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <tamaño>A3</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i248" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2430</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A3</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
</impresoras>
```

DOCUMENTO XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<!--elemento raiz-->
  <xs:element name="impresoras" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
<!-- hijo de impresoras-->
                    <xs:element name="impresora" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                           <xs:complexType>
                               <xs:sequence>
<!-- Secuencia de marca, modelo, peso, tamaño, cartucho, enred-->
                                    <xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="peso">
                                         <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveDecimal">
                                                    <xs:fractionDigits value="\d{2}"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                         </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="tamaño" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xs:element name="cartucho">
                                         <xs:simpleType>
                                             <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                               <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]\-\d{2}\[A-Z][A-Z]"/>
                                             </xs:restriction>
                                         </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="enred" minOccurs="0">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="positiveInteger"/>
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                  </xs:sequence>
<!--atributos numSerie, tipo y compra-->
                                 <xs:attribute name="numSerie" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                                 <xs:attribute name="tipo" use="required">
                                     <xs:simpleType>
                                         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:enumeration value="3D"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="láser"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="tinta"/>
                                         </xs:restriction>
                                     </xs:simpleType>
                                 </xs:attribute>
                                 <xs:attribute name="compra" type="xs: positiveInteger" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes unos cuantos errores, por ejemplo, al elemento principal no hay que ponerle ni `minOccurs` ni `maxOccurs`, esto se debe a que el elemento root solo tiene que aparecer una vez, tambien tienes otros errores de sintaxis, como por ejemplo, espacios donde no tenían que ir.

Te dejo como lo he resuelto:

**Documento XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <impresoras xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="yara_doamo_camila_impresoras.xsd">
  <impresora numSerie="i245" tipo="láser" compra="2010">
    <marca>Epson</marca>
    <modelo>EPL300</modelo>
    <peso>4.52</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <tamaño>A5</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-123BV</cartucho>
    <enred/>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i246" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2410</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i247" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2420</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A4</tamaño>
    <tamaño>A3</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
  <impresora numSerie="i248" tipo="matricial">
    <marca>HP</marca>
    <modelo>LaserJet 2430</modelo>
    <peso>3.2</peso>
    <tamaño>A3</tamaño>
    <cartucho>C-456P</cartucho>
  </impresora>
</impresoras>
```

**Documento XSD :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<!--elemento raiz-->
  <xs:element name="impresoras" >
        <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <!-- hijo de impresoras-->
                    <xs:element name="impresora" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                           <xs:complexType>
                               <xs:sequence>
                                    <!-- Secuencia de marca, modelo, peso, tamaño, cartucho, enred-->
                                    <xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="peso">
                                         <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                                    <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                                    <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                         </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="tamaño" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xs:element name="cartucho">
                                         <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                               <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]\-[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,2}"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                         </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="enred" minOccurs="0">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                  </xs:sequence>
                                <!--atributos numSerie, tipo y compra-->
                                 <xs:attribute name="numSerie" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                                 <xs:attribute name="tipo" use="required">
                                     <xs:simpleType>
                                         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:enumeration value="3D"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="láser"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="tinta"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="matricial"/>
                                         </xs:restriction>
                                     </xs:simpleType>
                                 </xs:attribute>
                                 <xs:attribute name="compra" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```